# Some CSS styles not applied in html when it as a mail using javax mail

Tags: java, html, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a formatted html as a mail using Javax mail API.
The mail util-code used is

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.setHeader("Auto-Submitted", "auto-generated");
message.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(commaSeperatedReplyTo));

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    if (body != null) {
       MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
       messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html;charset=utf-8");
       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    }
message.setContent(multipart);
```

And the html body generated was

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">

            #content ul li{
                display:inline !important;
                float:left;
                padding: 7px;
                margin-right: 4px;
                font-style: italic;

            }
        </style>

        <font face ="Arial" size=4> <U>DESCRIPTION</U>:Test </font><br/><br/>                       
            <div id="content">              
                <ul>
                        <li> component_id</li>
                        <li> component_type_id</li>
                        <li> name</li>
                        <li> update_user</li>
                        <li> update</li>
                        <li> key</li>
                        <li> field</li>
                </ul>                       

            </div>  
    </body>
 </html>
```

I am expecting this to display inline, not up and down. I tested the generated html in fiddle also. Working as expected. But, in the mail, i am getting it as normal list. Why inline display is not working in email?

need help

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with your code but with the fact that the mail client you are using doesn't support it.

Comment: The text is coming as `italic` because of italic style applied

Comment: @MrThys What to do then? I need it, any workaround for that?

Comment: My email client is: microsoft Outlook 2010

Comment: In my experience the best way to know that your mail will display properly in all clients is to use old-school HTML (tables) and use inline styles.

Comment: @MrThys I also tried inline styles. Not working

Comment: Agree with MrThys here. Email clients only tend to support inline styling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

E-mail-clients often do not follow standards. Some clients like gMail even ignore CSS-declarations in a `<style>`-block. [CampaignMonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/) has some great resources on how to create HTML-e-mails that are supported by most clients.

You should convert your layout to something like this (use tables!):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <font face="Arial" size=4><U>DESCRIPTION</U>:Test</font>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>component_id</td>
                <td>component_type_id</td>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>update_user</td>
                <td>update</td>
                <td>key</td>
                <td>field</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you can style the table/cells using inline CSS.

Comment: Yes.. Completed this. Thanks for the response. Saved my useless efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

How to use a css code to setContent method();
for example:

String css=" body {background-repeat: no-repeat;}";

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(css, "text/html");

//this css code is not affect the message body.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help]. You can also read about [answer].